Vector-valued measures on products
Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{G})$ be measurable spaces. Take now $X\times Y$ equipped with the product sigma-algebra, and consider two vector-valued measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $X\times Y$, with values in a Banach space.
Suppose that on product sets the two measures agree,
$$
\mu(A\times B) = \nu(A\times B) \quad \forall A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}.
$$
Can we conclude that $\mu=\nu$, just as it happens for real-valued measures?

I'm not completely familiar with the theory of vector-valued measures, so maybe I'm wrong. But assume the measures take values in the Banach space $X$. Then for any $\varphi \in X^\ast$, $\varphi \circ \mu$ and $\varphi \circ \nu$ are both real-valued measures, which coincide on all product sets, so $\varphi \circ \mu = \varphi \circ \nu$ for all $\varphi$, whence we should have $\mu = \nu$.
